# Navigation Back Stack Not working as expected when Hosting NavHost in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I have this use case where I want to host the BottomNav within a fragment
The Structure is like this Activity -> HostFragment -> Fragment 1 -> Fragent2 etc

Here is the set up

Activity XML

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="AMSHostFragment"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now XML from HostFragment

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="AMSHostFragment">


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/ams_nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_ams_bottom_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have hooked up the Setup from HostFragment like so

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
        navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                as NavHostFragment
        navView.setupWithNavController(navHostFragment.navController)
        //navView.setupWithNavController(requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment))
        //val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
        //val nacController = findNavController()
        //navView.setupWithNavController(nacController)
    }
```

The bottomNav view is working as expected when switching from one fragment to next

However when clicking on back the entire parent fragment is getting popped out
ie. when I go from Frag1 -> Frag2 and press back the Activity is getting closed

I checked the backstackEntry count it is always 1 no matter if I go to via Frag 1 ->  Frag2 -> Frag3

Ideally I would like to have the standard behaviour when I navigate back from Frag3 I should go to its previous Fragment .

If I put the bottom nav in activity then it is working fine in back stack case , however I need BottomNav in fragment for my use case .

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem except it doesn't work even in an activity.